# Shader from urp shader graph turns gray on webgl1 build

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-shader-graph, unity-webgl

When I build my game while graphics API is set to webgl1 the shader is just a gray texture.
It works fine if graphics API is set to webgl2 but I  need it to work on webgl1.
Can shader graph shader work with webgl1 at all or do I need another solution for my effect.

The graph:
[image]

The graph basically blurs and tiles the texture. I could sacrifice the blur part I already try that but I need the tiling.

Comment: Can you show us the offending graph, and what It's supposed to look like?

Comment: I edited the question so it includes the graph and an explanation of what it does.